# Add features in QGIS from an Excel sheet containing URL of the locations

Tags: qgis

I have an Excel sheet which contains the URL of the locations which I had pinned in the Google map (as shown in the below picture)

[image]

I need to add these point locations in the QGIS. How can I import these points in QGIS based on their URLs?

Comment: I removed the title and tag reference to ArcGIS since the Question body was focused on QGIS.

Comment: Thanks, @Vince. But I am comfortable with both GIS platforms. I need to find a way to convert these URLs into features irrespective of the GIS platform used.

Comment: @Anand, this was done to avoid your question being closed as [needing more focus](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions#:~:text=Needs%20more%20focus%20%2D%20If%20your%20question%20has%20many%20valid%20answers%20(but%20no%20way%20to%20determine%20which%2C%20if%20any%2C%20are%20correct)%2C%20then%20it%20probably%20needs%20to%20be%20more%20focused%20to%20be%20successful%20in%20our%20format.). It is better to ask a separate question per software platform, otherwise it is not possible to mark an answer as definitively correct.

Comment: Thanks, @Matt, for the rectification. Henceforth, I shall make sure not to commit this mistake again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert your Excel file into a CSV file, then :

1. Verify that the CSV is comma separated values (not tabs, semicolons, etc.)
2. Open the QGIS Data Source Manager <kbd>Ctrl + L</kbd>
3. Select the `Delimited Text` tab
4. Check the `Regular expression delimiter

   [image: QGIS import delimited text]
5. Enter as expression :

   ```
   https://www.google.com/maps/search/|,
   ```

   it will split your data by `https://www.google.com/maps/search/` or `,`, so it will create a field `Title`, `URL` (empty one), `Field3` (latitude), `Field4` (longitude).
6. You can define the geometry by select `Field4` as X Field and `Field3` as Y Field, with the SCR `EPSG:4326 WGS84`